# Duplicate item in dimens.xml

Tags: android

I am currently checking out the source code of Google's Dialer application.
However, I get a gradle build error: `Error: Found item Dimension/call_log_action_height more than one time`.

This makes sense, because the item *is* indeed a duplicate, as you can see here (first and last line):

```
<dimen name="call_log_action_height">48dp</dimen>
<dimen name="call_log_action_icon_margin_start">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="call_log_action_icon_dimen">24dp</dimen>
<dimen name="call_log_action_horizontal_padding">24dp</dimen>

<dimen name="call_log_actions_left_padding">64dp</dimen>
<dimen name="call_log_primary_text_size">14sp</dimen>
<dimen name="call_log_secondary_text_size">14sp</dimen>
<dimen name="call_log_list_item_actions_text_size">12sp</dimen>
<!-- Height of the call log actions section for each call log entry -->
<dimen name="call_log_action_height">44dp</dimen>
```

However, this is the source code from Google, and I checked out the VCS, it is also present in older versions of the file. How is this possible?

Comment: Are you looking at a crunched/packaged dimensions file, or the source dimens.xml?

Comment: Can you post a link to what you're looking at?

Comment: @milosmns it is the source

Comment: @milosmns https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/master/res/values/dimens.xml here you go

Comment: How strange, it is duplicated.. maybe you can just remove one? There are probably some internal optimizations and plugins that automatically get rid of duplicates..

Comment: @milosmns I think I will remove one. But I learned that it was not possible, and now I find this in the sources from... google. Strange world

Comment: Yeah, normally it is not allowed. Update here if you find out why it was allowed for them