# Load AOSP Application to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, import, android-source

I found a few questions asking how to get the source code from the AOSP running in Android Studio. However, I could not find any explanation on how to import only a single application of the AOSP.

I am trying to do it for the Dialer application which can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/kitkat-dev). However, I had only minor success, I was able to import the code as a project, but didn't manage to set up dependencies and required libraries and all that.

Can anybody tell me if it is possible, and if so, how this is done?

**UPDATE:**

It seems impossible to achieve this with the code that i found and which was part of the full android distribution of google. But google decided to distribute the Dialer application just like any other application via the playStore. So there should be a possibility to find this code, IF it is also running under the open source project.

Comment: "Can anybody tell me if it is possible" -- not usually. The AOSP apps usually are only meant to be built as part of a full firmware build, and they rely upon things that are not in the Android SDK. Occasionally, you can find an app that with some work can be separated out (K9 Mail is a fork off of an early edition of the AOSP Email app), but I would not expect the dialer to be so accomodating.

Answer (score 2):

You can only open the whole AOSP inside Android Studio.
After you finish building the source do  `make idegen && development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh` inside your root folder and then open the new android.ipr in your root via Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

AOSP code you are looking is not Android Studio compatible, It's an Eclipse project.

Comment: But would this solve my problem? Does it work when using eclipse?

Comment: I just tried it, and it did not work for me. I still have many missing dependecies, and the .xml files have errors inside as desribed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186201/duplicate-item-in-dimens-xml